# multiple entries same name html form

Tags: html, forms, lamp

1. Using HTML form with method GET, how to input large number of entries(more than 200) with the same name, say marks, that correspond to single column in MySQL table. Basically letting the end user enter the data serially.
2. After inputting the data how to retrieve them (>200) using PHP and how to update the table.

As a teacher I need to enter the marks of all students (for different subjects) at once and I want it to be done through browser.

Waiting for suggestions,

Ravi.

Comment: I suggest you to use PHP for that. Has array feature, works with HTML forms. So what do you want to do after waiting for suggestions if I may ask? How about cooking?

Answer (score 3):

1. Name your inputs: `name="whatever[]"`
2. They'll appear (at least in PHP) as an array:

   ```
   $_POST["whatever"] //This is an array of all the inputs named whatever[]
   ```

Comment: But I wish to give the choice to continue/finish entering the data to end user.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your get parameter ends with [], you can read multiple get values for this parameter as an array.

Example:

```
www.example.com/mypage.php?myparam[]=val1&myparam[]=val2&...
```

In php:

```
$mypar = array();
$mypar = $_GET['myparam'];
```

2.

```
// connect to the db here...
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");
for ($i=0;$i<count($mypar);$i++) {
    $sql ="insert into mytable values ($mypar[$i])";
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: www.example.com/mypage.php?myparam[]=val1&myparam[]=val2&... Not related to topic. I could not find an answer there.

Comment: @Ravikumar.Gurappa.Ganiger. I edited my answer with the php code to insert into mysql db, supposing your table has only one column.